# React js simple JavaScript https get request in method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, https, httprequest

I have a `react` function called bound on the constructor that gets called on the click of an "update" button.  Within that update method, I want to do a simple HTTPS get request something like this

```
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET","https://test", true)
xmlHttp.send(null)
enter code here
```

But I want to open a new tab when it does this
I have not imported Axios or anything else.

Comment: Take a look at the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: How to open tab: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843

Answer (score 0):

Don't forgot write callback of your xmlHttp

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = yourcallback
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET","https://test", true)
xmlHttp.send(null)
```

This works without needing to make changes but its better with the callback if you want to do any handling of the statuses that may be sent back.